# How to change the joining code?

Tags: programming

I'm trying to combine 4 matrices but I'm getting a matrix of 4x16 not 8x8.

```
A={{1,2},{2,3}};
B={{2,1},{3,3}};
DD={{4,5},{6,37}};
EE={{12,11},{13,14}};
```

[image: Trying this code]

[image: I'm getting this 4x16 matrix]

[image: However I need to get this form 8x8]
:

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [*ArrayFlatten*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html).

```
A={{1,2},{2,3}};
B={{2,1},{3,3}};
DD={{4,5},{6,37}};
EE={{12,11},{13,14}};
I2=IdentityMatrix[2];
```

The result is composed below.

```
ArrayFlatten[{{KroneckerProduct[I2,A],
    KroneckerProduct[Transpose[B],I2]},  
  {KroneckerProduct[I2 ,DD],
    KroneckerProduct[Transpose[EE],I2]}}]
```

and evaluates to :

```
{{1,2,0,0,2,0,3,0},
 {2,3,0,0,0,2,0,3},
 {0,0,1,2,1,0,3,0},
 {0,0,2,3,0,1,0,3},.    
 {4,5,0,0,12,0,13,0},
 {6,37,0,0,0,12,0,13},
 {0,0,4,5,11,0,14,0},
 {0,0,6,37,0,11,0,14}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works perfectly. Many thanks.